# Python3 Comparison, Script Execution on linux, wrong output

Tags: python-3.x, linux

I am very new in python3 programming language. May anyone take a look, what is wrong with my code?

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
x = input("enter the first number: ")
y = input("enter the second number: ")
z = input("enter the third number: ")
def max(x, y, z):
    if x>=y>=z:
            return x
    elif y>=x>=z:
            return y 
    else:
            return z
print('Maximal Number is: ' + max(x, y, z))

root@kali:~# ./Comparision.py
```

enter the first number: 26

enter the second number: 768

enter the third number: 9

Maximal Number is: 9

---

enter the first number: 563

enter the second number: 96

enter the third number: 86

Maximal Number is: 86

Thank you in advanced,
Dena

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things.

- You're comparing strings rather than integers, and for strings "9" > "10" is `True` because strings are compared digit by digit (or letter by letter). If you want to compare the actual numbers, you need to parse the strings to integers, e.g. like this: `x = int(x)`, `y = int(y)`, etc.
- In the second example it should have printed the `y` value but the situation looked like this: `y>=z>=x`, but this case wasn't handled so your code hit the `else` and it returned `z`.

Overall, unless what you're doing is some kind of exercise, I suggest using the built-in `max` function:

```py
>>> max([1, 2, 3])
3
```

If you're just practicing then still, writing conditionals is not the best way of finding the maximum value of a set of numbers. This problem is typically solved with an algorithm using a `for` loop, which can handle arbitrarily large collections of numbers with just a single `if`, e.g.:

```py
In [1]: def my_max(arr):
   ...:     retval = None
   ...:     for x in arr:
   ...:         if retval is None or x > retval:
   ...:             retval = x
   ...:     return retval
   ...:

In [2]: my_max([1, 2, 3])
Out[2]: 3
```

Comment: thank you for your advices Czaporka! I am just practicing "if, else" lesson :D' . it is not working again even I specified the variables as int. Maybe the reason is what you explained, not the best option for this kinds of calcualtion. Thank you :)